# tabs in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, controller

I am currently facing some issues related to ionic-tabs and Floating tabs concept.

Currently using ionic framework..I am building a mobile app in which I want **tabs** to get **fixed** below header once the page is scrolled till the position where the tab is. I have kept ion-tabs inside ion-content.

After getting the scroll position I have added a class "fixed". 
    As it adds the class fixed,the background changes to white (no content visible) and the tabs get hidden instead of getting fixed at the position below header.

```js
$scope.onScroll = function() {

    var scrollWidth = $(".bar".height() + $(".maincontent".height(); console.log($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition()); console.log(scrollWidth);
          if (parseInt($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top) > scrollWidth) {

            $('ion-tabs').addClass('fixed');
          } else {
            $('ion-tabs').removeClass('fixed');
          }
        };
```

```css
.fixed {
  left: 0;
  top: 44px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ion-view>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-positive">
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content on-scroll="onScroll()">
    <div class="main-content">

      <!-- some content here -->

    </div>
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-dark tabs-background-positive tabs-striped tabs-top">
      <!-- About Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="About">
        <ion-nav-view>
          <div>
            <!--some tab content -->
          </div>
        </ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <!--update Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Updates">
        <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right">
          <ion-view>
            <ion-content scroll="false">

              <!-- some other tab content -->

            </ion-content>
          </ion-view>
        </ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated your question more clearly.

Comment: My question is related to getting ionic tabs fixed while scrolling. I want tabs to get fixed at the position below my main header.. jus like the subheader component in ionic but after scrolling.. I am facing problems in making it fixed. I came to know about the fact that placing ionic tabs inside the ionic content does create some css bug but don't know how to get the problem resolved. I hope i am bit clear now.

Comment: did you try fixing it? i too experience the same problem in my ionic application

Comment: yes we have fixed our tabs using an alternative approach..  the tabs that we kept inside the ion-content we allow it to get scrolled up .. and have displayed the other fixed tabs (copy of the same tabs but just the different id) in that position using jquery .. we took the height of our whole content and when the height of our content gets greater than the height where we have to display our fixed tabs , we kept it fixed

Comment: @Asra, Are your tabs equally distributed??

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing with the ionic.css file and I found a solution for fixed tabs, but like I say you will have to edit the ionic.css file.

You must edit this:

```css
.tabs-top.tabs-striped
{
   padding-bottom: 0;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 9999
}
.tabs-top > .tabs, .tabs.tabs-top 
{
  top: 44px;
  padding-top: 0;
  background-position: bottom;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999 
}
```

With this you will have the ion-tabs fixed, but if you want that bar-header will also be fixed, then edit this

```css
.bar-header 
{
  top: 0;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999 
}
```